# Optimising search on primary key for large table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I've got a MySQL table with about 100,000 records. When I try to select about 20 rows from this table using the primary key (an unsigned int) it takes about a second to execute. Is there any way to optimise this?

**Table: films**

```
Column          Type        Null    Default 
film_id         int(11)     No       
film_name       varchar(45) No       
film_overview   text        No       
film_tagline    varchar(150)Yes     NULL     
release_date    date        Yes     NULL     
api_id          int(11)     No       
category_id     int(11)     No      0
```

**Indexes on films**

```
Keyname         Type    Unique  Packed  Column      Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY         BTREE   Yes     No      film_id     110236      A           No  
api_id          BTREE   No      No      api_id      110236      A           No  
film_id         BTREE   No      No      film_id     110236      A           No  
category_id     BTREE   No      No      category_id 4           A           No
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
id  select_type         table           type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             films           ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    115029  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  popular_films   ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    18      Using where
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT film_name FROM `films` 
  WHERE film_id in (SELECT film_id FROM popular_films);
```

Comment: Please show schema, query and `EXPLAIN` output.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN`, put the results in the question as well..

Comment: @Undefined: no you didn't. Your explain output includes a subquery, so that means you aren't doing a simple lookup with 20 keys. Show the whole query.

Comment: Your query does not include category_id and yet that is part of the plan.  Is that really the query?

Comment: Part of the plan? I don't need the category_id?

Comment: What is the definition of `popular_films`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to think it can use your primary key.  Can you add the structure for popular_films, please?  You might also try `SELECT film_name FROM films, popular_films WHERE films.film_id=popular_films.film_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've added the query, the answer is simple: just use a join:

```
SELECT films.film_name
FROM `films`
JOIN popular_films
  ON popular_films.film_id = films.film_id;
```

It looks like your popular_films table has the same structure as films, and so probably shouldn't be a separate table.